# Is it possible to redefine 0 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, fixnum

I'm not actually going to use this in anything in case it does actually work but is it possible to redefine 0 to act as 1 in Ruby and 1 to act as 0? Where does FixNum actually hold its value?

Comment: I'm pretty sure numeric literals are handled by the parser, since you can't `def 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. I'd be very suprised if you managed to. If you start overriding Fixnum's methods/operators, you maaaybe might get near that (i.e. override + so that 1+5 => 5, 0+5 => 6 etc), but you will not get full replacement of literal '0' with value 1. At least marshalling to native would expose the real 0 value of the Fixnum(0).

To be honest, I'm not really sure if you can even override the core operations like `+` op on a Fixnum. That could break so many things..

As far as I remember from 1.8.3 source, simple integers and doubles are held right inside a 'value' and are copied all around *). There is no singular "0", "1" or "1000" value. There is no extra dereference that would allow you to swap all the values with one shot. I doubt it changed in 1.9 and I doubt anyone got any weird idea about that in 2.0. But I don't actually know. Still, that would be strange. No platform I know interns integers and floatings.. Strings, sometimes array literals, but numbers?

So, sorry, no `#define true false` jokes :)

--

*) clarification from **Jörg W Mittag** (thanks, this is exactly what I was referring to):

> (..) Fixnums do not have a place in memory, their pointer value is "magic" (in that it cannot possibly occur in a Ruby program) and treated specially by the runtime system. Read up on "tagged pointer representation", [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25744887/2988).

Answer (score 0):

> Assignment does not alias Fixnum objects. There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum. Any attempt to add a singleton method to a Fixnum object will raise a TypeError. [Source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html)

That pretty much means you can't edit a Fixnum and therefor not redefine `0` or `1` in native ruby.

Though as these Fixnums are also Objects they have unique object id's that cleary reference them somewhere in the memory. See [BasicObject#__id__](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__)

If you can locate the memory space where `0` and `1` objects are and switch these, you should have effectivle switched `0` and `1` behavior in ruby as now either will reference the other object.

So to answer your question: No redefining Fixnums is not possible in Ruby, switching their behaviour should be possible though.

Comment: Actually, in MRI, YARV, Rubinius, MRuby, MacRuby and possibly others, `Fixnum`s do not have a place in memory, their pointer value is "magic" (in that it cannot possibly occur in a Ruby program) and treated specially by the runtime system. Read up on "tagged pointer representation", e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25744887/2988).

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks, this is much better description of the mechanism than the "right inside the 'value'" I came up with. I allowed myself to incorporate your comment in the text, hope you don't mind.